# Unrelated symbols appear in private symbol server while debugging

Tags: debug-symbols, symbol-server

We have a private symbol server (just a folder in a shared network drive). 
A while ago I noticed it contains symbols for many DLLs which aren't ours (System.Xml, clr, kernel32, etc.).
The `_NT_SYMBOL_PATH` environment variable is set to `SRV*c:\symbols*G:\Foundations\Symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols` where `c:\symbols` is my local cache and `G` is mapped network drive. This is according to the instructions here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee416588(v=vs.85).aspx#symbol_servers.

Today I finally figured out how all the non-private symbols got there. I deleted the clr.pdb folder from the private symbol server and started debugging a dump using ClrMD. Instead of only saving the clr symbols in my local cache they also reappeared in the private symbol server.

How do I prevent this from happenning? I don't want our private symbol server to contain unrelated garbage which just takes up space and clutters the folder. [We already have about 2600 folders there, probably 90% are not ours. I can't imagine how to clean this up...]

*UPDATE 1*:

So it turns out that this is in fact the expected behavior, as documented by a **different** MSDN page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681416(v=vs.85).aspx.

According to *yet another* documentation page (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680689(v=vs.85).aspx) using a `cache` element marks a certain folder as cache. However setting `_NT_SYMBOL_PATH=CACHE*c:\symbols;SRV*G:\Foundations\Symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols` didn't prevent addition of symbols to the private symbol server and setting `_NT_SYMBOL_PATH=CACHE*c:\symbols;SRV*G:\Foundations\Symbols;SRV*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols` caused a weird behavior: VisualStudio was able to download symbols and they didn't end up in my private symbol server, however, ClrMD was unable to download symbols for the dump I was analyzing... When I opened the same dump in VS it worked fine. So I guess ClrMD somehow does something different with the symbol path...

Comment: From the link you provided, in Best Practices section : _Set up an automated build system to index symbols on your private symbol server for each build that is produced._ Is there a possibility that this might be involved? Maybe all it needs is some configuration regarding which symbols actually end up in the private server.

Comment: No, I see the symbols appear when I start debugging, not when I just build.

Comment: Yep, you're right. Have you checked [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnetsamples/blob/master/Microsoft.Diagnostics.Runtime/CLRMD/docs/GettingStarted.md#getting-the-dac-from-the-symbol-server) for ClrMD?

Comment: I call 
_target.AppendSymbolPath(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("_NT_SYMBOL_PATH"));
ClrInfo dacVersion = _target.ClrVersions[0];
string dacLocation = dacVersion.TryDownloadDac();
Doesn't work. Maybe I'll try to debug it later with the ClrMD source.

Answer (score 0):

### Your first attempt

First, you mention the symbol path

```
SRV*c:\symbols*G:\Foundations\Symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
```

According the documentation you linked

> As symbols are retrieved, files and folders appear in the \mainserver\symbols shared directory, as well as in individual caches, in the c:\symbols directory.

So that's the intended behavior.

### Your second attempt

The second symbol path you used was

```
CACHE*c:\symbols;SRV*G:\Foundations\Symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
```

which consists of two parts:

```
cache*c:\symbols
```

(which is fine) and

```
SRV*G:\Foundations\Symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com
```

which is (from syntax point of view) identical to

```
srv*c:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
```

and described like this on the linked MSDN documentation:

> To use only the Microsoft symbol server together with a local cache of symbols, to speed up access over the Internet, use the following setting for _NT_SYMBOL_PATH: `srv*c:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols`

So yes, it will download Microsoft files to `G:`.

### Your third approach

Your last try was

```
CACHE*c:\symbols;SRV*G:\Foundations\Symbols;SRV*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
```

The `srv*http...` syntax (without a defining a local folder) is not described on any of the linked documentation, So I'm not sure what behavior that would cause.

### My proposal

```
SRV*c:\symbols*G:\Foundations\Symbols
```

should download private symbols from G: to C:. And

```
SRV*c:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
```

should download symbols from Microsoft to C:. So combine them to

```
SRV*c:\symbols*G:\Foundations\Symbols;SRV*c:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
```